# Парабола касательная к 2м прямым

Tags: математика

Есть прямая **y=0.35**x; и прямая с неизвестным параметром  **y=0.6x+z**. И есть касательная к ней парабола с параметром **y=ax^2+0.35x**. Парабола должна быть касательной к обеим прямым (**у=0,35х** уже касательная в точке **(0,0)** ) и к **у=0,6х+z**; касание должно быть при **y=324**. и потому надо вычислить параметры **(a,z**) и **x** при котором оно все выполняется.
Так оно должно иметь только одно решение уравнения в точке **у=324**.

Проверил графически себя в маткад но это не результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При подборе параметров в маткад дает рекурсию скорее всего от того что неправильно записую условия неправильно что то в условии. Попытка вычислить аналитически через систему **yk=y0+y'(x0)(x-x0**) уводит меня к натуральным логарифмам которые аж никак не помогли вычислить коефициенты так как **y'=(yk-y0)/(x0)(x-x0)** и при интегрировании выходит **ln....** что не помогает вычислить коеффициенты.

Comment: Ну аналитически же ж решается. Ищи точку пересечения y=0.6x+z с параболой в зависимости от z (квадратное уравнение, два корня), и ищи соответственно z, при котором корни совпадают (дискриминант равен нулю - получишь линейное уравнение).

Comment: Ну то 2 корня это когда пересекаются в 2х точках а мне надо в одной точке по касательной. И при решении диффура я получаю интеграл дроби с которой вылазит натуральный логарифм и не дает ничего, просто перемножая мои параметры друг с другом. При параметре дискриминанта приравнивании его к нулю я получаю а, но тогда оно не связано с касательной, а если искать точку пересечения то выходит система: {y=ax^2+0.35; y=0.6x+z; y=324} Тогда  с системы снова 2 параметра друг с другом перемножаются.

Comment: *Ну то 2 корня это когда пересекаются в 2х точках а мне надо в одной точке по касательной.* Касательная - это та прямая, у которой обе точки пересечения с параболой совпадают/сливаются.

Comment: Да, надо приравнять дискриминант к нулю, перед этим уравнявнять ax^2+0.35=0.6+z=324. Но тогда  дискриминант = -0.25^2-4a*(324+z). и тогда с него не вытащить значения параметров так как они перемножились.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

«Вычтем» из параболы неизвестную прямую. Получим

```
y = ax^2 - 0.25x - z
```

Из условия, что прямая касалась параболы в некоторой точке, можно построить систему уравнений `y = 0` и `y’ = 0`

```
ax^2 - 0.25x - z = 0   (1)
2ax - 0.25 = 0         (2)
```

Тут два уравнения и три неизвестных, так что решить её нельзя, но тем не менее можно получить зависимости между `a` и `z`. Из уравнения **(2)**

```
2ax = 0.25 = 1/4 <=>
x = 1/(8a)
```

подставляем `x` в уравнение **(1)**

```
a(1/(8a))^2 - 1/4 * 1/(8a) = z <=>
1/(64a) - 1/(32a) = z <=>
-1/(64a) = z <=>
a = -1/(64z)
```

а именно `a = -1/(64z)`.

Таким образом, для любого значения `z` (кроме `0`) есть такое значение `a`, что парабола и прямая касаются друг друга.

Теперь найдём точку касания. Подставим найденное соотношение в уравнение **(2)**

```
2ax = 1/4 <=>
-2x/(64z) = 1/4 <=>
x = -8z                (3)
```

Таким образом мы нашли координату `x` точки касания. Подставим **(3)** в исходное уравнение прямой (`y = 0.6x + z`)

```
y = 0.6x + z <=>
y = -24z/5 + z <=>
y = -19z/5             (4)
```

таким образом мы нашли координаты точки касания (**(3)**, **(4)**)

```
x = -8z
y = -19z/5
```

Comment: Тут можно покрутить переменную `z` (она там названа `b`) https://www.geogebra.org/m/nkbvwyen

Comment: а как мы узнаем точку пересечения (x = -8z
y = -19z/5):?

Comment: @Boris, в смысле? Это и есть точка касания (пересечения).

Comment: я имел ввиду как мы ее вычисляем? Ну когда мы приравниваем х и y до нуля  в уравнении (2zx)/64=0.25 то тогда не получаеться получить это число. Приравняв уравнения друг к другу тоже не получилось.   Это как раз правильный ответ и на графике все замечательно сходиться.

Comment: @Boris т.е. вы не можете понять откуда взялись последние равенства?

Comment: Да, я последние не понял как были выведены. Остальное все разобрал и графически все верно. Просто непонятно как к этому прийти.

Comment: @Boris обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Пишем графики параболы и прямых :

```
парабола a*x^2+0.35*x
левая 0.35*x
правая 0.6*x+z
```

их производные :

```
парабола 2*a*x+0.35
левая 0.35
правая 0.6
```

наклон параболы == наклон правой

```
2*a*x+0.35 == 0.6
```

место правой прямой при касании == 324

```
0.6*x+z == 324
```

место параболы при касании == 324

```
a*x^2+0.35*x == 324
```

Три уравнения и три неизвестных решаем :

```
2*a*x+0.35 == 0.6
a = (0.6-0.35)/2/x= 0.125/x

a*x^2+0.35*x == 324
(0.125/x)*x^2+0.35*x == 324
0.125*x+0.35*x == 324
x = 682.105

0.6*x+z == 324
0.6*682.105+z == 324
z = -85.2632

a = 0.125/x = 1.833e-4
```